# I'm looking for a book (I think?) with a perfectionist spellcasting girl, that is masochistic

Tags: story-identification, magic

I'm looking for a book with a spellcasting girl who sets goals for herself, and when she can't do it, she increases her goal for the next day.

The goals were like, "Cast this spell 100 times" and if she failed, "Cast this spell 200 times, with my left hand" or something.

I think she was one of two apprentices to a magic teacher, and the other student just did her spells well enough to just be able to cast it.

---

**Possibilities**

I want to say it was a book by Tamora Pierce, but I don't remember any character that acts like that in her books, but *maybe* it wasn't magic, so maybe it was [Keldry](https://tamorapierce.fandom.com/wiki/Keladry_of_Mindelan), who trains with weighted gear and maybe other handicaps?

It's English, and wasn't recently published. I think I read it in Canada in 2010?

**It might be a fanfic, in which case I'd likely never find it again? But I do think it's a physical book...**

---

**What else have I read**

- The Inheritence Cycle
- Dresden Files
- Children of the Lamp
- [Septimus Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septimus_Heap)
- Micheal Scott's Alchemist series
- The Seventh Son series
- [The Bonemender series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bonemender_(book_series))

Comment: Does not sound like a Tamora Pierce book, as far as I remember.

Comment: This is... almost certainly not the work you're thinking of, but the behavior reminded me of a story, a manga, my brother was talking about, where a character (Rock Lee, and I think also his teacher, Maito Gai) would set all kinds of impossible goals for himself, and also set increasingly worse goals if he failed each task.  But male, not female, and physical goals(do so many laps, and if I fail, do twice as many on my hands, or something like), not magical ones.  Like I said, probably not the right one - it just seemed similar.

Comment: @Megha - Yeah. From Naruto. It does seem similar... ... I wonder if my book could actually be translated from Japanese? ... But, no, I'm quite sure it isn't a manga or Light Novel or something like that?

Comment: Have you read any Trudi Canavan?  It makes me think of Magician's Apprentice.  I don't recall that bit for sure, though.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magician%27s_Apprentice

Comment: @eshier - Doesn't seem familiar. Never seen nor heard of her, so I don't think so.

Comment: @AdeleC - I wanna say it's Jory from Cold Fire, but I don't have a copy atm...

Comment: Definitely not Kate Daniels. None of the main characters cast spells that way.   (The closest thing Kate has to spells are her Power Words, and *one* of those wipes her out, much less 100).  Not any other Ilona Andrews either.

Comment: @AdeleC - What do you remember of Kel's training? I just remembered that she does it weird.

Comment: @Malady Not sure what you mean about Kel's training being weird. But she does not have any magical gift. Just recently reread Protector of the Small series.

Comment: @eshier - As in she does more training or something compared to the rest of the recruits, like the weighted equipment that I mentioned. Does she ever do anything like the kind of practice that I mentioned? 100s of repetitions of anything?